# Laravel: how to pass data from controller to repository

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Can anyone help me, I would like to pass id to my repository.
the output is `illegal offstring id`
thanks for your response!

this is my controller

```
public function delete()
{
   $response = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid request'];
     if (Request::ajax()) {

        if (Request::isMethod('POST')) {

        $data = Request::input('id');

        $response = $this->testRepo->delete($data);

        }
    }

   return Response::json($response);

}
```

this is my testRepo->delete

```
public function delete($data) 
    {
        $data = $data['id'];

        $result = DB::table('user_details')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('id', '=',$data);

        if ($result) {
                    // delete 
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Share the code of your view as well please @Russell

Comment: in controller, what does `var_dump($form_data)` print?

Comment: $form_data contains the value at 'id' so how would parse_str know the key @Russell

Comment: @Russell where are u getting undefined index id. In javascript?

Comment: @amitgarg I changed some codes and now its showing illegal offstring id

Comment: @Russell Are you able to see the id in console with `console.log(account_id);`?

Comment: @amitgarg yes, It passes through the js correctly. I think the problem goes in here : 
    $data = Input::get('id');

Comment: @Russell Can you change ` $response = $this->testRepo->delete($data);`  to  `$response = ['status' => true, 'id'=>$data, 'message' => 'Invalid request'];` to check if you are going into the line to delete statement?

Comment: @Russell Try `$data = Request::input('id');`

Comment: use this$this->request->get('id') and in your route use get.

Comment: @amitgarg it worked! but I want to pass the id to the `testRepo->delete($data)`

Comment: I changed the construction of codes above. thanks

Comment: @Russell https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#deleting-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this you are storing the id value, not an array:

`$data = Request::input('id');`

So in this case `$data` holds the actual id.

If you want to send the entire input array you can do that like this:

`$data = Request::all();`

Then retrieve it like this:

`$id = $data['id'];`